# Is there any online resource on Yitang Zhang's biography?

Tags: mathematicians, reference-request

Where I should look for a biographical note on Yitang Zhang's life. I read the wikipedia article but it does not provide any in depth perception on his life. There is nothing on [here](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/). If anybody knows some sources then please give me a pointer. Thanks.

Comment: In [this answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/who-are-some-great-scientists-mathematicians-with-not-so-great-pre-mid-career-cr/2055#2055) I linked some biographical material. In particular, [this interview](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/02/02/pursuit-beauty). See also [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=zhang+yitang+interview&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=7xdkVtaAFoGJav-1rVg)